Unusual substitution to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$
I was trying to calculate the Dirichlet integral using Complex integration and I was trying out a different substitution from the one that is usually employed to solve the problem, i.e. $\operatorname{f}\left(z\right) = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}z}/z$, that is I was trying to use the Residue theorem on $\sin\left(z\right)/z$ on a half circumference centered at the origin, extrema on real axis and radius $R \to \infty$.

The integral over the entire curve vanishes because the function is analytic on the whole complex plane ( we can consider the analytic extension of the function to remove the singularity at zero ) so I am left calculating
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm i}
\sin\left(R{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta}\right)
{\rm d}\theta
$$
which is the contribution of the contour integral from the half circumference.
Here is my problem: in the limit $R\to\infty$ the integrand seems to diverge because by writing
$$
\sin\left(z\right) =
\frac{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}z} - {\rm e}^{-{\rm i}z}}{2{\rm i}}
$$
and expanding the terms in the exponents I get a term ${\rm e}^{R\sin\left(\theta\right)}\times$(terms of modulus $1$) from ${\rm e}^{-{\rm i}z}$ whereas the first term contributes to zero in the limit.

Obviously the integral has to be finite, so what am I doing wrong ?.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: since the integrand is even, write your integral as$$\frac12\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}z}-1}{z}\mathrm{d}z.$$

You correctly conclude that the integrand $i\sin(R e^{i \theta})$ becomes infinitely large for $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $0 < \theta < \pi$. However, in that limit the integrand is oscillating infinitely fast and this gives the integral a chance of having a finite limit. And indeed you have shown that
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d} x = -\frac{1}{2}\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\pi i\sin(R e^{i \theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{1}{4} \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\pi \exp(-i R e^{i \theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta \, .$$

Oh I see, now it makes sense, thank you!
